# The size of data written to stream obtained from IO#pipe

Tags: ruby, io

I'm using [IO#pipe](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe) method and at some point I want to know how many bytes have already been written into the output stream. Using [IO#tell](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-tell) causes error which isn't much helpful - `Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument` - it doesn't say what is invalid where.
There is a trivial code snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```
read_io, write_io = IO.pipe
write_io.tell #=> #<Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument>
```

Is there a way to write my own `tell` method? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
irb(main):007:0> read_io, write_io = IO.pipe
=> [#<IO:fd 9>, #<IO:fd 10>]
irb(main):008:0> read_io.tell
Errno::ESPIPE: Illegal seek
    from (irb):8:in `tell'
    from (irb):8
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):009:0> write_io.tell
Errno::ESPIPE: Illegal seek
    from (irb):9:in `tell'
    from (irb):9
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

On my Ruby console, it returns `ESPIPE` and not `EINVAL`, which is expected because `tell` is implemented using `lseek` in Unix environments, which returns `ESPIPE` if the file is a [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/lseek.html).

We can measure the amount of data written/read to the pipe by keeping an counter that accumulates results of `read()` and `write()` calls on the pipe.